# Elasticsearch an array contains at least one element

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use elasticsearch for search recipes by tags

```
{
  ...
  "tag": [
      "cool",
      "cooler"
  ]
},
{
  ...
  "tag": [
      "cool",
      "hard"
  ]
},
{
  ...
  "tag": [
      "coolest",
      "hardest"
  ]
},
```

I want search all entities that contain exactly "cool" tag

What was I try:

```
GET /recipes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tag": ["cool"]
    }
  }
}
```

Return nothing

```
GET /recipes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tag": "cool"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Return nothing

```
GET /recipes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tag": "cool"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Return all entities

How do I retrieve only items that does contain "cool" and possibly another values but the rule is that the tag must exist in a tag array

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /recipes/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {"wildcard" : { "tag" : "cool*" } }
            ]

     }
}
```

Comment: Falls on tags like "beef:rump"
`GET /recipes/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
              "wildcard" : { 
                "tag" : "beef:rump*" 
              } 
            }
          ]
     }
   }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This solution using script query [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html)

```
GET /recipes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['tag'] instanceof List && doc['tag'][0].contains('cool')"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The scripts are ok , but this one return items with only one tag and does not retrieve items like ['tag' => ['smoke', 'cool']]

Comment: I edited the question to retrieve the results you want, i thought first you want to retrieve the list with one item which is 'cool'